# Swift non actor isolated closures

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, actor

Do escaping closure that are passed to actor method inherit actor isolation? Or they are non isolated?

For instance:

```
actor MyActor {
   func method(_ closure: @escaping () async -> Void) {
      await closure()
   }
}
```

With what isolation will closure be created?
In my simple test, seems that closure inherit it's context isolation on allocation

```
actor MyActor {
   func method(_ closure: @escaping () async -> Void) async {
       print("in actor method: ", Thread.current)
       await closure()
       print("in actor method: ", Thread.current)
   }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let actor = MyActor()
        Task {
            print("in task closure: ", Thread.current)
            await actor.method {
                print("in actor closure: ", Thread.current)
                try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
                print("in actor closure: ", Thread.current)
            }
            print("in task closure: ", Thread.current)
        }
        
        return true
}
```

Outputs:

```
in task closure:  <_NSMainThread: 0x283604380>{number = 1, name = main}
in actor method:  <NSThread: 0x283654400>{number = 5, name = (null)}
in actor closure:  <_NSMainThread: 0x283604380>{number = 1, name = main}
in actor closure:  <_NSMainThread: 0x283604380>{number = 1, name = main}
in actor method:  <NSThread: 0x283654400>{number = 5, name = (null)}
in task closure:  <_NSMainThread: 0x283604380>{number = 1, name = main}
```

I know that it's it proper proof of hypothesis, therefore I'm asking: Is there are any proposals or statements, which describe what isolation async closure do get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the closure will use the same actor context from which it was formed (the main actor in this example):

As [SE-0306](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0306-actors.md#closures) says

> A closure that is not `@Sendable` cannot escape the concurrency domain in which it was formed. Therefore, such a closure will be actor-isolated if it is formed within an actor-isolated context.

---

If you do not want the closure running on the actor from which it is formed, you have a few options:

1. You can make the closure `@Sendable`. As [SE-0306](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0306-actors.md#closures) says:

   > Actors [specify] that a `@Sendable` closure (described in [`Sendable` and `@Sendable` closures](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0302-concurrent-value-and-concurrent-closures.md), and used in the definition of `detach` in the [Structured Concurrency](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0304-structured-concurrency.md) proposal) is always non-isolated.

   Thus,

   ```swift
   actor MyActor {
       func method(_ closure: @escaping @Sendable () async -> Void) async {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

   That results in the closure being non-isolated (i.e., not running on the actor where the closure was created).
2. You can also explicitly specify the closure’s actor. You could specify a global actor:

   ```swift
   @globalActor
   public struct SomeGlobalActor {
       public actor SomeOtherActor { }

       public static let shared = SomeOtherActor()
   }

   actor MyActor {
       func method(_ closure: @escaping @SomeGlobalActor () async -> Void) async {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, it's interesting. Need to deep dive into @Sendable. I thought it just adds some restrictions on the compilation steps, without any isolation changes

Comment: The `@Sendable` makes the closure non-isolated (meaning that it doesn't have to run on the caller’s actor). Updated above with relevant excerpt from SE-0306.